# Anonymous function returning 1 using #()

Tags: clojure

Using defn or fn it's easy to create a function that taking one argument that ignores it and returns 1:

```
(defn ret1 [arg] 1)
(fn [arg] 1)
```

Is it possible to do this with the #() macro?  I don't mean using something ugly or "cheating" like

```
#(/ % %)  or 
#(if (nil? %) 1 1)
```

I mean literally ignoring the parameter and returning 1. I can't find a clean syntax that works.

Comment: This works - getting closer.. #(last (list % 1))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The #() syntax can't be used to create functions that have unused parameters in the way your description requires. This is a limitation of the #() reader macro.

I would recommend *not* using #() and instead just writing (constantly 1) which is a very brief way to create a function that ignores a parameter and instead always returns 1.

Comment: *The #() syntax can't be used to create functions that have unused parameters*  Sure it can (see my answer), but it's not the best way.

Comment: @drcode Please admit that the answer is wrong. Like you, I'd never have thought of inserting a stray `%&` to invoke an arbitrary argument list.

Comment: @drcode ... or not? It's arguable that mentioning arguments, even without evaluating them, constitutes *use*. But they are certainly *ignored*, as the question requires.

Comment: @Thumbnail: Let it hereby be known to all regarding an answer I gave 4 years ago that I admit to being wrong, stipulating certain specific interpretations for the words "ignored" and "ugly".

Comment: @drcode LOL ... and I'll call attention to anyone who resorts to uselessly using a split infinitive.

Answer (score 29):

`#(do %& 1)` ... but `(constantly 1)` is better.

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's cleaner than my last attempt using #(last(list)).  I like also that you generalized it to any number of parameters using %&.  The original question was inspired by SICP 1.37 which stipulates using (lambda (i) 1.0) to return 1.0. The obvious mapping to clojure was (fn [i] 1) but I got to wondering how to do it with #().  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about `#(identity 1)`? which does the same thing as `#(do %& 1)` or `(constantly 1)`.