# In Clojure, what is the idiomatic way to define anonymous function with argument not used?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

Instead of:

```
(run-jetty (fn [request] (response "hello")) 6789)
```

I want (to ignore the give parameter):

```
(run-jetty #(response "hello") 6789)
```

I.e., I want to use anonymous function to save a few typing. Clearly it will raise error at runtime  as the the anonymous function will be given a parameter(i.e., request) which it doesn't want to handle . So what is the idiomatic way to achieve that ?

Comment: The convention is `(fn [_] ...)`.

Comment: Yes @A.Webb, but as I'm still studying Clojure, I want to explore more options to hone my skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your exact use, but I would the [`constantly`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/constantly) function.

```
(run-jetty (constantly (response "hello")) 6789)
```

If you're trying to delay the computation with an anonymous function then this won't work (hint: use [`delay`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/delay) and [`force`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/force) in that case), but for ring handlers it will work nicely.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Also,I'm Wondering how do you guys find out those functions... Is it simply that you've read a lot of Clojure code or you have some special method to search in the APIs ?

Comment: I've mostly just read a lot of Clojure code. I also try to read blogs about Clojure (a fair few people tend to write blog posts when they find useful functions they haven't seen before). I don't have any special ways to search the APIs, unfortunately.

Comment: Got it. I write [blog](http://wangjinquan.me/show/Clojure%20%E7%BA%BF%E6%80%A7%EF%BC%88%E7%AE%AD%E5%A4%B4%EF%BC%89%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E7%AC%A6) for my own studying too. So there is no crosscut for this. I need to keep studying the same way ;-)

Comment: "how do you guys find out these functions" - http://clojure.org/cheatsheet the cheatsheet links to some out of date docs, and has some gaps, but is very helpful despite all that.

Answer (score 3):

I found my question is duplicated with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005437/anonymous-function-returning-1-using).

Also I found the `constantly` is really **constant** : It will cache the result for the subsequence usage. Although it's not what I want, it's good to know:

```
demo1.core=> (defn foo [] (rand))
#'demo1.core/foo
demo1.core=> (def aa (constantly (foo)))
#'demo1.core/aa
demo1.core=> (aa)
0.8006471724049917
demo1.core=> (aa 1)
0.8006471724049917
demo1.core=> (aa 1 2)
0.8006471724049917
```

Just in case somebody else like me are looking for same thing.

Comment: A very good point to make. `constantly` is a function, so it takes a **value** to return. This means that your `(foo)` is only evaluated when `constantly` is first called, not on subsequent evaluations `aa`.

Comment: @mange, I don't think it's the fact "`constantly` is a function which take a **value** " that make it **constant**. Because,you know,every thing is a *value* in clojure, especially, function is absolutely real **value** . `constantly` is *constant* simply because it is implemented that way, IMHO